# Changing a text in multiple AEM pages at multiple locations

Tags: aem, query-builder, findandmodify

I have a website hosted on AEM. I want to change a text that is present in almost all pages (say I want to change my product name which is present in all pages) . How can i do it. It can either be a Groovy/Java code or an ondeploy script or anything else. Because doing it manually on all pages at multiple locations is not feasible. Will AEM Bulk Editor solve the purpose?

Its like Find and replace functionality in office

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to have a set of queries to find most of the references and then make a POST to these pages with the new value.

Example with: `curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD -F"PROPERTY=new value" "http://$HOST/content/mysite/en/page/jcr:content"`

Of course, you can do it with Java, Groovy (look for Groovy Console for AEM, which is very convenient), or even bash for simpler cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query using the query builder api to get all the nodes where your particular property is present.
Then once you get the path to that property you can update that using the node api.